# gltail "Missing gem net-ssh"

Tags: rubygems, net-ssh, gltail

I'm attempting to get gltail set up on my local system to monitor logs remotely.

I've got all the dependencies installed, but when I go to run gltail ...

```
./gl_tail configfile ../config.yaml
```

I get this output:

```
Missing gem net-ssh.
Ubuntu:
  sudo gem install -y net-ssh -r
```

.. which I've done a number of times. Here is the output:

```
dev@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Fudge-gltail-e5b252d/bin$ sudo gem install net-ssh
Successfully installed net-ssh-2.0.15
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for net-ssh-2.0.15...
Installing RDoc documentation for net-ssh-2.0.15...
```

But when I go to run it again, I get the same missing gem net-ssh error.

```
dev@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Fudge-gltail-e5b252d/bin$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
dev@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Fudge-gltail-e5b252d/bin$ which gem
/usr/bin/gem
```

Why isn't net-ssh being seen as properly installed?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 10.04:

```
sudo gem uninstall net-ssh
sudo gem install net-ssh -v 1.1.4
sudo apt-get install libopenssl-ruby1.8
sudo gem install net-ssh-gateway
```

From: https://github.com/Fudge/gltail/issues/2